# uploading multiple docs in php... need to act on file base on ID in form

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

So we have a form that has multiple upload fields.

```
<input name="uploads[]" type="file" id="pre" />
<input name="uploads[]" type="file" id="post" />
```

What we need to do is loop through the uploads as they come in and get the id of that uploaded file. This id will trigger what we need to do with these files (where to store, what to name, sql statements, etc). I am not sure this is even possible as the loop through the uploaded files doesnt seem to touch the ID of the POST. The $_FILES["uploads"]["name"] does me no good as I don't know the name of the files they are dropping. I just need to loop and attach some identifier besides the name.  Can I do something with the name? Can I look through the POST items and check for IDs being present?

Comment: Name them as upload_pre[] and upload_post[]. Form field Id won't be passed. You can use Ajax if you want to pass the id too.

Comment: So how would we loop to see what names have been loaded? foreach($_FILES['files'] as $file) { } is what I would use but the FILES['files'] no longer flies because each of those files has a different name? Do I have to make a look at each individually? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do a var_dump($_Files). It will give you an idea what is being passed from these fields

Comment: $_FILES['pre']['name']!=="" ... we got it! Thanks